# is IEnumerable enumerated on call of the method or when enumerating the response

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I want to know weather an IEnumerable parameter to a method is enumerated when I call the method or when I enumerate the return of the method, assuming we have the following code:

```cs
IEnumerable<T> ProcessList(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    foreach(var element in list)
    {
        yield return ProcessElement(element);
    }
}
```

I am mostly curious how to write Where-Linq like extensions.

Comment: You can find out your self by putting a brakepoint inside your loop. But my best guess is that it is enumerated upon enumeration of the result.

Comment: If you want to create Linq like extension methods you should check out [Edulinq](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/) by Jon Skeet.

Comment: You can write enumerations that return infinitely long sequences (e.g. `while (true) return 1;`) and you will be able call the method that returns the enumeration without it taking infinitely long. Only "enumerating the enumerator" will start going through the loop.

Comment: thanks! While I could have tested this myself, i think the answers will be a good reference for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `list` (`enumerable`) is only enumerated when the result of `ProcessList` (`enum2`) is enumerated:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var enumerable = Enum1();
    Console.WriteLine("Enum1 retrieved");
    var enum2 = Enum2(enumerable);
    Console.WriteLine("Enum2 called");
    foreach (var e in enum2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<string> Enum1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enum1");
    yield return "foo";
}

private static IEnumerable<string> Enum2(IEnumerable<string> enumerable)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enum2");
    foreach (var s in enumerable)
    {
        yield return s;
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
Enum1 retrieved
Enum2 called
Enum2
Enum1
foo
```

The last three lines are only printed when entering the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use of the `yield` keyword means that this snippet of code will evaluate only as needed to provide the results you use. In other words, this will not cause evaluation:

```
var processed = ProcessList(unprocessed);
```

The contents of the result list don't matter, so they won't be evaluated yet. However, if you do this:

```
var processed = ProcessList(unprocessed).ToList();
```

this will ask it to evaluate the `IEnumerable`, which will cause it to run your code. Likewise, if you do this:

```
var processed = ProcessList(unprocessed);
foreach (var x in processed)
{
    DoSomething(x);
}
```

it will run your `ProcessElement()` method for each element in turn. To take this further, if you do this:

```
var processed = ProcessList(unprocessed);
foreach (var x in processed.Take(10))
{
    DoSomething(x);
}
```

because you're only using the first 10 items of the result list, it will only run your `ProcessElement()` method for those 10. The rest will only be evaluated when you come to use them.